# SFDMU - Deleting 30 Millions records

Tags: data-loader, data, delete, bulk-delete, salesforceexcelconnector

I deleted 30M records with SFDMU.
The only issue I faced was that I have to update the Json file for every 900,000 records and re-trigger the job using sfdx sfdmu:run --targetusername Production.

By doing this way I have to be there in front of the laptop all day, and every 20 minutes, update the query and re run the command.

I want to be able to automate the command and don't have to re-write the query to match a limit of 900,000.

If I just leave a query that the number of records counts goes over 1 Million the job will fail and say Query Time out.

I hope this time makes sense.

I did check all about the limits of BULK API v2 and changed the JSON configuration several times to see if I could get some different results.
I tried also to do multiple queries in the JSON but it did not work.

Comment: Did you already delete (from your statement 'I managed to delete 30 mil') or you are looking to delete 30 mil but you are able to delete only 1mil so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: N.B. [SFDMU](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility)

Comment: Is this a one time operation or do you plan to do this regularly? How many more records would you like to delete? If this is a one time operation than you could just write a small script to have your computer start a new batch after the previous one is finished.

Comment: Hi @Kasper 
It will be a regular operation but only max 2millions at the time from now on in prod. I have the apex now to schedule that job.

However sometimes i load the performance testing with a lots of records i found sfdmu the best for this. so I wonder why all about the query that describe above.

Kind Regards and Thanks a lot

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://help.sfdmu.com/faq/common-questions/are-there-any-limitations-regarding-the-processed-data-volume) there shouldn't be a limit on the number of records but there are a lot of Salesforce API limits . An easy solution to the API limits would be to write a simple script that launches the next command after the previous is done. Depending on your needs that could be only a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @Kasper, yes that's a great idea about the script but it seems to have to be updated on regular bases to match the query that won't go over the limit. I think the best option might be the APEX which also allows the hard delete function. I'm going to try that soon.

Comment: Hi @Kasper, I used the BatchDelete Apex and works fine . Managed to delete 1500000 records in 8hrs. Its slower than sfdmu but I'll just schedule and I wont need to monitor.

Comment: Great to hear @SandraZuluaga, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [old bug from 2017](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/697) in the `jsforce` plugin that fails to query more than 1m records. It's been also reported [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility/issues/522) in the sfdmu repo, with some workarounds ...